# trying to make textarea autogrow upwards instead of downwards (i have the textarea in a footer

Tags: jquery, css

Can you grow a textarea upwards instead of downwards, I have the textarea in a footer. I am using textarea-expander.js 
I dont know what to do, at first I was going to do a margin-top and minus an increment every time I pushed the enter key but realised that would not work correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/jquery.textarea-expander.js"></script>   

<style>
#postbox {
width: 400px; 
height: 150px; 
border:1px solid #ccc;  
position: fixed; 
margin-left: 40%; 
bottom:0;
border-bottom: none;
}
</style>

<div id='postbox'>
<textarea id='box_area' class="expand" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: create a jfiddle so we can check and change some code for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the fixed height on your footer div, or at least put a `min-height` only.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

CSS:

```
textarea{
position:absolute; 
bottom:0;
}
```

or

HTML:

```
<textarea cols="10" rows="1" class="expand" id="box_area" style="height: 90px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;"></textarea>
```